# How to make back navigation by tap NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

My template is:

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" text="Back" (tap)="goBack()"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>
```

How to write function `goBack()` to move back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Angular, you can use `RouterExtensions` from the `nativescript-angular` package. Specifically, call `routerExtensions.back()`. Here's a complete inline example:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" text="Back" (tap)="routerExtensions.back()"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>`,
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    constructor(public routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {
    }
}
```